# Java Config for Spring Web Service Marshallers

Tags: spring-ws

I have been trying to switch from XML configuration to Java configuration for Spring Web Services.  The only element I can't seem to do is the marshallers.

The XML line:

> annotation-driven marshaller="xmlBeansMarshaller" unmarshaller="xmlBeansMarshaller"

should be replaced with the Java class annotations:
`@EnableWs` 
`@Configuration`,
but I can't seem to find how to setup the marshallers in code.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marshallers can just be registered by using a regular `@Bean` definition. For instance, consider [this sample app configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples/blob/master/mtom/server/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/samples/mtom/config/MtomServerConfiguration.java#L62).